# Filtrar en columna agrupada para detectar texto

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en Pyhon y estoy aprendiendo a programar un screener de acciones que cumplan ciertos criterios.
Mi código genera un dataframe ordenado por frecuencia de señales SOS que mi código va detectando y los agrupa por Ticker.

```
     JSON solamente de ejemplo
data = {
    'Ticker': ['SEDG', 'SEDG', 'SEDG', 'PEP', 'PEP', 'PEP','CTLT'], 
    'SOS': ['Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol', 'Test in Rising', 'Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol', 'Shakeout', 'Test'],
    'Date' : ['2021-12-14', '2021-12-16', '2021-12-18', '2021-12-14','2021-12-16','2021-12-18','2021-12-20']
}

# Creamos el dataframe desde un JSON:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Resultado:

```
  Ticker             SOS        Date
0   SEDG  Absorption Vol  2021-12-14
1   SEDG    Stopping Vol  2021-12-16
2   SEDG  Test in Rising  2021-12-18
3    PEP  Test in Rising  2021-12-14
4    PEP  Absorption Vol  2021-12-16
5    PEP        Shakeout  2021-12-18
6   CTLT            Test  2021-12-20
```

El problema lo tengo ahora porque estoy bloqueado y no sé cómo seguir. Del dataframe de arriba me gustaría filtrar sólo aquellos tickers que tengan en la columna SOS las señales 'Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol' y 'Stopping Vol'.
Es decir sólo quiero mostrar por pantalla qué tickers cumplen estas 3 señales, si sólo muestra una no me sirve, necesito detectar cada ticker en que aparezcan esas tres señales.

Quiero que mi resultado sea este:

```
  Ticker             SOS        Date
0   SEDG  Absorption Vol  2021-12-14
1   SEDG    Stopping Vol  2021-12-16
2   SEDG  Test in Rising  2021-12-18
```

Ya que elimina todos los demás tickers y sólo muestra el que cumple las tres señales. Estoy intentando hacer un for loop en la columna Ticker con este código pero no me funciona

```
tickers = final_df_sos['Ticker'].drop_duplicates()
for ticker in tickers:
    cond = final_df_sos[(final_df_sos['SOS'][ticker].str.match('Test in Rising')) & (final_df_sos['SOS'][ticker].str.match('Absorption Vol')) & (final_df_sos['SOS'][ticker].str.match('Stopping Vol'))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITO:

- Creamos el dataframe de ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

# JSON solamente de ejemplo
data = {
    'Ticker': ['SEDG', 'SEDG', 'PEP', 'CTLT', 'SEDG'], 
    'SOS': ['Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol', 'Test in Rising', 'Test', 'Test in Rising'],
    'Date' : ['2021-12-14', '2021-12-16', '2021-12-14', '2021-12-14', '2021-12-14']
}

# Creamos el dataframe desde un JSON:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Con esto tenemos un dataframe de ejemplo:

```
  Ticker             SOS        Date
0   SEDG  Absorption Vol  2021-12-14
1   SEDG    Stopping Vol  2021-12-16
2    PEP  Test in Rising  2021-12-14
3   CTLT            Test  2021-12-14
4   SEDG  Test in Rising  2021-12-14
```

En este caso aplicaré:

- `isin`: Para seleccionar los valores donde la columna `SOS` se encuentren entre la lista proporcionada.
- `groupby`: para agrupar por la columna deseada, en este caso `Ticker`
- `filter` para filtrar. En este caso estamos seleccionando donde el resultado de agrupar sea 3 elementos

```
SOS_values_filter = ['Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol']
print(df[df['SOS'].isin(SOS_values_filter)].groupby('Ticker').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3))
```

Resultado:

```
  Ticker             SOS        Date
0   SEDG  Absorption Vol  2021-12-14
1   SEDG    Stopping Vol  2021-12-16
4   SEDG  Test in Rising  2021-12-14
```

Esto sería en una consulta SQL lo siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 'SOS' IN ('Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol', 'Stopping Vol')
GROUP BY 'Ticker'
HAVING count(*) = 3;
```

Esto solo aplica si cada Ticker es una key de donde el SOS no se pueda repetir. En caso de que se repita el SOS más de una vez ya no cumpliría la condición del `having`.

Comment: Utilizar el 'loc' y 'isin' me sirve para no repetir el 'str.match' pero sigo sin poder sacar como resultado los tickers en que se cumplan las 3 opciones. Sólo puedo filtrar la columna SOS en base a esos criterios, pero sólo quiero que me muestre los tickers que cumplan las 3 condiciones. Gracias por la aportación para sustituir el 'str.match'

Comment: Sinceramente no pillo lo que necesitas exactamente. En este caso filtro cuando SOS sea alguna de esas 3 opciones ( 'Test in Rising', 'Absorption Vol' y 'Stopping Vol'), el resultado es el dataframe sin el resto de opciones en SOS, solo esas 3. No sé si podrías explicarme un poco más, quizá pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Oh vale, creo que lo entiendo. Necesitas que el ticker, por ejemplo, SEDG, aparezca con las 3 opciones, ¿correcto?

Comment: Correcto! Disculpa que me haya explicado tan mal...

Comment: Muchas gracias! Creo que estoy a un paso de conseguirlo, con tu método me filtra todos los tickers y los agrupa, pero no me muestra solamente los que cumplen las 3 señales, sino que muestra si cumplen alguna de las 3. Quiero que cumplan las 3 a la vez para mostrarlo. 
Ahora mismo me saca los que cumplen alguna de ellas:
`     Ticker             SOS        Date  frequency
5320   ZNTL  Absorption Vol  2021-12-16          4
5321   ZNTL  Test in Rising  2021-12-20          4
5322   ZNTL  Test in Rising  2021-12-27          4
5323   ZNTL  Test in Rising  2021-12-30          4`